# Computing a new variable in Stata based on existing variables

Tags: variables, stata, generate

I am not well versed in Stata, and I am struggling to find the right syntax to generate a new variable based on the properties of several other variables.

I have one dummy variable indicating sex (`Sex_at_birth`), and 3 dummy variables indicating sexual orientation (`isHE`, `isBI`, `isHO`). I want to create 3 dummy variables indicating sexual preferences (`likesMEN`, `likesWOMEN`, `likesBOTH`).

An example logical statement I'd like to use would be:

```
likesMEN = 1 if ((Sex_at_birth = 1) & (isHE = 1)) | ((Sex_at_birth = 0) & (isHO = 1)), 
else likesMEN =0
```

It would be analogous for the other variables.

I am at loss on how to code it in Stata, and I believe it will be like 2 seconds for someone who knows the program well.

Note: I know that I need `n-1` number of dummy variables to code a variable that has 3 categories, and I will have that in mind when conducting analyses. However for my dataset I want to have all of the categories dummy coded (so I can chose which one to omit for my analyses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question.

You just need to use `==` instead of `=` in your expression:

```
clear
set obs 20

local varlist Sex_at_birth isHE isBI isHO

foreach var of local varlist {
    generate random = runiform()
    generate `var' = 0
    replace `var' = 1 in 1/10
    sort random
    drop random
}

generate likesMEN = ( (Sex_at_birth == 1) & (isHE == 1) ) | ///
                    ( (Sex_at_birth == 0) & (isHO == 1) )
```

You then get:

```
. list

    +------------------------------------------+
    | Sex_at~h   isHE   isBI   isHO   likesMEN |
    |------------------------------------------|
 1. |        0      1      1      0          0 |
 2. |        0      0      0      1          1 |
 3. |        0      1      0      1          1 |
 4. |        1      0      0      1          0 |
 5. |        0      1      1      1          1 |
    |------------------------------------------|
 6. |        1      1      1      1          1 |
 7. |        1      0      1      0          0 |
 8. |        1      0      1      0          0 |
 9. |        1      0      0      1          0 |
10. |        0      1      1      0          0 |
    |------------------------------------------|
11. |        1      0      0      0          0 |
12. |        0      1      1      0          0 |
13. |        0      0      0      1          1 |
14. |        0      1      0      1          1 |
15. |        1      0      0      0          0 |
    |------------------------------------------|
16. |        1      1      0      1          1 |
17. |        1      1      1      0          1 |
18. |        1      1      1      0          1 |
19. |        0      0      0      0          0 |
20. |        0      0      1      1          1 |
    +------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't know it'd be that easy - was thinking along the way that I'd need to define the values of the new variable, depending on the values of the old variables, didn't know that STATA will automatically put ones everywhere the condition is met, and zeros where it isn't, in the new variable.

Comment: Just remember to use the double equals `==` to test for equality and Stata will do the rest.

Comment: I actually know that Stata uses == for 'equals' in logical statements, I wasn't writing a stata code in my question, but a logical statement I wanted to translate into Stata code.

Comment: https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/ gives further discussion.